# AngularJS custom tag to insert AJAX response

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Using AngularJS with jQuery I am looking to use my own tag  like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <mytag foo="bar" baz="qux">
  <mytag alpha="beta" gamma="delta">
</div>
```

and having each  substituted with the HTML response that gets returned from these GET method invocations:

```
$.get("http://www.example.com/service?foo=bar&baz=qux");

$.get("http://www.example.com/service?alpha=beta&gamma=delta");
```

I can't seem to locate a similar example anywhere so I asking for help here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/qAZVhm

I do not think it is a good idea of doing this as it is
not trivial to distinguish standard html attributes from your own attributes.

What do you expect for the element like: `<mytag foo="bar" class="error">` for example?
Do you expect `class` attributes to work for styling? or ajax path definition?

Comment: I don't know what my attribute names will be yet but they will be fixed names that avoid a conflict such as you describe. So instead of <mytag foo="bar" baz="qux"> there will be something more meaningful such as <mytag date="1/1/2010" user="hamilton">